# German character Encoding issue in Decompiler

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding

> Hi guys,
>
> I am facing one ecoding related issue. Actually there is a need to decompile a .class file  and modify few lines and again compile it
>   back.
>           I used a open source tool and download it to decompile the class, now I am copying that coode in Eclipse to change the lines and
>   to compile it back.
>           The problem is that the .class file contains some german character, as soon as I copying that code in eclipse it is showing all
>   of them as junk characters.
>           I changed the ecoding to UTF-8 in Preferences- workspace section but still getting the junk characters.
>           Any help to know how to do it without getting the junk characters?
>           Attaching the sample of German characters in a decompiler

[image]

After copying in eclipse editor: These character are showing as junk.
Even copying it in Notepad++ is not working for me.
[image]

Comment: Please show the junk and be more specific, e. g. how you copied the code into Eclipse. The encoding can be set on workspace, project, folder and file level. The more specific setting is used. So make sure the file uses UTF-8 (right-click + _Properties: Resource_).

Comment: Hi, I have added the image of the junk character after changing the file encoding to UTF-8. I simply copy the code from the decompiler (ctrl+C) and pasted it in Eclipse file (ctrl+V)

Comment: The fact that the characters are displayed incorrectly in Notepad++ indicates that the characters are already incorrect in the clipboard. Therefore I guess that something already goes wrong when using Ctrl+C. Please describe how you copy the code to the clipboard so that everyone can reproduce it.

Comment: I am just selecting the code using Ctrl+A or selecting a piece of line using mouse. After selecting it , I don't see right click as option to copy. So I am just copying the selected text using Ctrl+C.

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct. May be the clipboard is copying the text as junk. Not sure how to make that .class file in Decompiler as editable.

Comment: Thank god I got the solution. I copied the text from decompiler and pasted it first in Microsoft Notepad. Then I copied it back to java file. It worked :-). Thanks buddy for you help.

Comment: In Windows, copying a string to the clipboard leads to, depending on the application where you do Ctrl+C, the same string in different formats (for example, plain text, RTF, HTML, etc.). The target application (where you do Ctrl+V) selects one of the formats. It is therefore possible that copying via a third application helps. Great that you found a solution. Please give a self-answer.